# (Symfony3/php7) Cannot use object of type AppBundle\Entity as array

Tags: php, symfony, entity

I have an error: "*Cannot use object of type AppBundle\Entity as array*", and it makes no sense for me, imo it's okay.

```
if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {
            $user = $form->getData();
            $repository = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository(User::class);
            $findUser = $repository->findOneBy(['username' => $form->getData()['username']]);
            if ($findUser) {
                return $this->redirectToRoute('login');
            }
```

Error **Cannot use object of type AppBundle\Entity\User as array** is at line with "*$findUser =*"

Can someone explain my why isn't it working?

Symfony 3.3, PHP 7

Comment: by the way, if any answers to your questions ever helped you, it would be useful for others to mark those answers as the right ones. I'm not talking about my answer, I'm talking about all of your questions, that still go "unanswered".

Comment: @AlexKarshin sorry, I have no idea how to mark a comment as a right answer :p Many of my questions have unhelpful answers, so I am not marking them as right ones.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This example [here](https://symfony.com/doc/3.3/forms.html#handling-form-submissions) explains everything:

```
$form->handleRequest($request);

if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {
    // $form->getData() holds the submitted values
    // but, the original `$task` variable has also been updated
    $task = $form->getData();

    ...
}
```

Thus, `$form->getData()` holds the entity. So, if your `User` entity has a `username` attribute, you should call it as `$form->getData()->getUsername()` or whatever getter you have there.

Answer (score 3):

Usualy when you get error like this you have to check data type. If variable is array you can access it only as array using `$variable['index'];`, if it is object you can access it using `$variable->index;`. Best way to figure out variable type is to use `print_r($variable);` or `var_dump($variable);` and it will output variable type for you. In your case you will use `print_r($form->getData());` or `var_dump($form->getData());`. If you use wrong way to get data from variable (array/object) you will receive (Cannot use object of type) error.

If it is array (in your case it isn't):

```
$form->getData()['username'];
```

If it is object:

```
$form->getData()->username;
```

if your framework has getters and setters:

```
$form->getData()->getUsername();
```

Comment: Can you please explain your answer so it’s not a code only answer

Answer (score 1):

It seems you doesn't see differences between objects and arrays. Let's say you have an object (class) `Car` and that object has a property e.g. `type` set to 'Van'. Now you want to get this type. How you do it? Using `->` symbol.

```
$car = new Car();
echo $car->type; //Van
```

Now we have an array `$car` with named index `type` set to `Muscle`.

```
$car = ['type' => 'Muscle'];
echo $car['type']; //Muscle
```

You cannot treat Object as Array and vice versa. You have Entity (which is just a class, object) so you have to treat it like an object.

So if you have Entity `User` you access its properties using `->` not `[]`.